# Normal map DXT5 compression in Vulkan

Tags: rendering, vulkan, image-compression, dxt

In DX10, it is common practice to compress normal maps by placing the Y value in the green channel, and the X value in the alpha, and apply DXT5 compression (the Z component is then reconstructed in the shader). What is the corresponding format in Vulkan? The closest i can find is VK_FORMAT_BC5_UNORM_BLOCK, which is unsigned RG channels with DXT5. Is this equivalent? If so, would you store it as R: X and G: Y or the other way around (does it matter)? Or are there newer compression formats that do a better job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DXT5 was [renamed to BC3 in DX10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-resources-block-compression). Vulkan's equivalent compressed texture formats follow the DX10+ naming convention. So `VK_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM_BLOCK` is exactly what you're used to using.

That being said, using DXT5/BC3 for normal maps was outdated a decade ago, even in the DX10 days. The common way to handle that nowadays is to use BC5 to store the X and Y components, generating Z in the shader. You get better quality for the same texture size.

But the even more modern equivalent is to use [BC7 with a 2-channel, separate encoding mode](https://www.khronos.org/registry/DataFormat/specs/1.3/dataformat.1.3.html#BPTC). Though this requires more advanced compressors.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! It seems like UE4 and Unity both still use DXT5 for their normals, so it can't be quite that outdated - but still, great to know, i'll stick to BC5 from now on. ;)